# How to show many normal distribution curves in one plot

Tags: plotting

I have about 30 PDFs (normal distributions). The mean of each is 0.386, but every one has a different standard deviation. I want to show them all together in a single plot with different color and name (line 1, 2, 3, ...)

I can plot a single PDf and then using `Show`, I can show them together, but it takes too much time. I have to `Plot` every single one of them and then I have to use `Show`. But can I do it quickly using a single line?

Comment: Please see [Mathematica docs on this topic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[n, 4], x], {x, 0, 30}], {n, 6, 16, 2}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 Filling -> Axis,
 PlotLegends -> Range[6, 16, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: `PDF[NormalDistribution[.386, n], x],` looks more like the OP's question :)

Answer (score 2):

Since V 12.3 we have `ListLinePlot3D`:

```
plot = 
  Transpose @ Table[{i, x, PDF[NormalDistribution[0.3, 0.3 i], x]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}, {i, 10, 20}];

ListLinePlot3D[plot, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
SeedRandom[987];
obs = RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[3, 1, 5], {10, 20}];
foo = PDF @* SmoothKernelDistribution /@ obs;

ListLinePlot3D[
 Transpose @ Table[Through @ foo @ u, {u, -5, 10, 0.1}],
 AxesStyle -> White,
 TicksStyle -> White,
 Background -> Black,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1},
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit",
 ImagePadding -> 30,
 ViewPoint -> {3, 2, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Show[
 Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{i, x, PDF[NormalDistribution[.386, .3 i], x]},
   {x, -5, 5},
   PlotStyle -> Hue[i/30],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-4, 4}, {0, .5}}],
  {i, 1, 30}],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]